# lxml give ROOT name attribute and xml file a version

Tags: python, lxml, openpyxl

**EDIT****Other aim:** 
And I would love to iterate through every excel row and save each row as separate .xml file (filename = invoice.text)
any help appreciated
->>> the problem is, that the 2nd created .xml file has also data  from the first row inside. Can anybody help me? Highly appreciated

help is appreciated, I want to give ROOT name attributes and the xml a version "" and save each excel row as a separate .xml file

I already setup the excel with openpyxl.
[image: data formatted already with openpyxl from source file]

**EDIT** 
Code edited

```
from lxml import etree
import openpyxl


# Create root element with namespace information
xmlns = "http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040"
xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
schemaLocation = "http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040 Belegverwaltung_online_ledger_import_v040.xsd"
version = "4.0"
generator_info = "DATEV Musterdaten"
generating_system = "DATEV manuell"

xmlRoot = etree.Element(
    "{" + xmlns + "}LedgerImport",
    version=version,
    attrib={"{" + xsi + "}schemaLocation": schemaLocation},
    generator_info=generator_info,
    generating_system=generating_system,
    nsmap={'xsi': xsi, None: xmlns}
)

####open excel file speadsheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('import_spendesk_datev.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Import']

# build the xml tree
for i in range(2,6):
        #consolidate = etree.SubElement(xmlRoot, 'consolidate', attrib={'consolidatedAmount': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=16).value, 'consolidatedDate': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value, 'consolidatedInvoiceId': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value, 'consolidatedCurrencyCode': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=12).value )})
        consolidate = etree.SubElement(xmlRoot, 'consolidate', attrib={'consolidatedAmount': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=16).value),'consolidatedDate': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value), 'consolidatedInvoiceId': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value), 'consolidatedCurrencyCode': str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=12).value) })
        accountsPayableLedger = etree.SubElement(consolidate, 'accountsPayableLedger')
        account = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'bookingText')
        account.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=21).value
        invoice = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'invoiceId')
        invoice.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value
        date = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'date')
        date.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value
        amount = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'amount')
        amount.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=16).value
        account_no = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'accountNo')
        account_no.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=19).value
        cost1 = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'costCategoryId')
        cost1.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=15).value
        currency_code = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'currencyCode')
        currency_code.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=12).value
        party_id = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'partyId')
        party_id.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=20).value
        bpaccount = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'bpAccountNo')
        bpaccount.text = sheet.cell(row=i,column=20).value
        #doc = etree.ElementTree(xmlRoot)
        #doc.write( str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value)+".xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
        doc = etree.ElementTree(xmlRoot)
        with open(str(sheet.cell(row=i,column=13).value)+".xml", 'w') as f:
                f.write(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))



# doc = etree.ElementTree(xmlRoot)
# with open("test1337.xml", 'w') as f:
#     f.write(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))


# convert into elementtree and write it directly into a file
#doc = etree.ElementTree(xmlRoot)
#outFile = open("test1337.xml", 'w')
#doc.write("test1337.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
#doc.close()
```

Please help sitting like hours on that.
Thanks so much

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add "other aim" after you have accepted the answer.

Comment: Ok i delete. I opened already other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using etree elements and subelements and convert them later on into a element tree. This provides more flexibility while creating the xml, especially when you want to iterate over an existing data structure:

```
from lxml import etree

# Create root element with namespace information
xmlns = "http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040"
xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
schemaLocation = "http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040 Belegverwaltung_online_ledger_import_v040.xsd"
version = "4.0"
generator_info = "DATEV Musterdaten"
generating_system = "DATEV manuell"

xmlRoot = etree.Element(
    "{" + xmlns + "}LedgerImport",
    version=version,
    attrib={"{" + xsi + "}schemaLocation": schemaLocation},
    generator_info=generator_info,
    generating_system=generating_system,
    nsmap={'xsi': xsi, None: xmlns}
)

# build the xml tree
consolidate = etree.SubElement(xmlRoot, 'consolidate', attrib={'consolidatedAmount': "1337.01"})
accountsPayableLedger = etree.SubElement(consolidate, 'accountsPayableLedger')
account = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'bookingText')
account.text = 'amazon'
invoice = etree.SubElement(accountsPayableLedger, 'invoiceId')
invoice.text = "1"

# convert into elementtree and write it directly into a file
doc = etree.ElementTree(xmlRoot)
with open("test1337.xml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
```

The generated file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<LedgerImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040" generating_system="DATEV manuell" generator_info="DATEV Musterdaten" version="4.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xml.datev.de/bedi/tps/ledger/v040 Belegverwaltung_online_ledger_import_v040.xsd">
  <consolidate consolidatedAmount="1337.01">
    <accountsPayableLedger>
      <bookingText>amazon</bookingText>
      <invoiceId>1</invoiceId>
    </accountsPayableLedger>
  </consolidate>
</LedgerImport>
```

Comment: thank you so much, that worked, iam currently working on: 1. iterate/loop through the excel spreadsheet and put the values per row in 1 xml file and save that one file. Hope I can figure out by myself. The name of each file need to be the invoiceId column from excel

Comment: actually sorry this error is shown in terminal:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spendesk_print.py", line 40, in <module>
    doc.write(outFile, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2056, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 758, in lxml.etree._tofilelike
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 318, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 682, in lxml.etree._FilelikeWriter.write
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: really thx a lot, do you know how i can save each excel row as one seprate .xml file ? :)